# How to create AD User in sitecore via custom API?

Tags: user-management

The Membershipprovider doesnt seem to create an AD user from custom c# API.  While logging in via Azure AD sitecore automatically creates the AD user and maps the roles as per the transformation rules.

But my objective is to create the AD user using my custom API, The user gets created with the Membershipprovider methods, but while logging in it recreates another user in sitecore with the same Email ID and a random user id as string. How do i prevent that?

Tried extending the UserResolver , But doesnt seem to hit the service.

Comment: You need to take a look at the user builder https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/91/sitecore-experience-manager/configure-federated-authentication.html#configure-virtual-and-persistent-users

Comment: Hi Lui, Tried the steps in sitecore, But the service doesnt seem to hit, trying via logs, but is there any customization done around authentication pipelines ?

Comment: User Resolver working, But wondering if Ad user creation is achievable with API